# How to return data from CRM 2011 javascript odata function?

Tags: javascript, odata

This seems silly that I haven't been able to accomplish this. I'm using the common code found on the web to do an odata query. The problem is the results stay in getFieldData(retrieveReq) routine. I don't want to immediately set a field on the current form. How can I get my values out of it so the data can be used in other javascript functions? Global variable would be good but nothing I've tried has worked. The below code displays "x".

```
var var1 = "x"; odataquery(); alert(var1);
```

The example given [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc2840ca-a420-4665-9d15-b2f0c245d35c/how-to-retrieve-business-unit-id-of-user-using-javascript-odata-in-ms-crm-2011?forum=crmdevelopment) has two alerts that display the data. How can Id and Name get outside of that function to be useful?

Edit1: Below is the main part of the routine that calls getFieldData(this). I want to use OwnerBUID and OwnerBUName in other javascript functions.

```
    var retrieveReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    retrieveReq.open("GET", odataSelect, false);
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    retrieveReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        getFieldData(this);
    };
    retrieveReq.send();

function getFieldData(retrieveReq) {
    if (retrieveReq.readyState == 4 && retrieveReq.status == 200) {  
        // 4=request complete, 200=OK
        var retrieved = this.parent.JSON.parse(retrieveReq.responseText).d;
        var retrievedValue = retrieved.results[0].BusinessUnitId;
        OwnerBUID = retrievedValue.Id;
        OwnerBUName = retrievedValue.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what your `odataquery();` function looks like.

Comment: Please see Edit1 for more info. Thank you!

Comment: Well the first thing that comes to notice is that you're calling `getFieldData(this)` while your other function actually is named `getFieldData_owner(retrievedReq)`

Comment: I'd suggest you try to step through your request with the debugger of your choice to see what happening and what's probably going wrong.

Comment: I updated the code to remove the _owner part so it resembles the web examples more. There is nothing going wrong. I want to be able to use the data in variables OwnerBUID and OwnerBUName outside of these combined two functions. How can I pass the data out so it can actually be useful in other functions?

Comment: It's not explictly in your question but I guess your real problem is to declare a global variable outside the scope of your (OnChange?) event handler - maybe [this thread on form global vars](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/16b6d24e-30eb-4065-a78c-6e116d7281da/global-variables-for-a-single-entity-crm-2011-jscript?forum=crm) is helpfull.

Comment: Much thanks Filburt. I think the global variable wasn't working before because I was calling the routine before the onload happened. I moved the global declaration and routine call inside the onload and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to put the data as the return value of a javascript function. You could do this: 
var returnedData = function getFieldData(retrieveReq)
{
...
return data;
}

BTW, you could consider to use JayData, Breeze and Datajs sources code packages in your client application. They implement the low level APIs for consuming an odata service using javascript.